# QGIS on android4 with bluetooth GPS

Tags: gps, android

I'm trying to set up a moving map on my tablet (asus, Android 4). 
I've installed QGIS (latest version), which works. I've got a blue tooth external GPS, which I've paired to the tablet. However, I cannot link the GPS to QGIS.

I followed the steps on QGIS website "go to View-> Panels-> " but no other page comes up.

Any suggestions?